# how to create 2d array in python if we know number of rows,and number of columns depends on some condition?

Tags: python

My array maximum dimension could be 2x27,but number of columns could be lower than 27.Number of columns depends on some condition.Is good solution to initialize array 2x27 and then delete unnecessary columns or has more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Here's what _doesn't_ work. Looks reasonable in the interpreter but it makes references to the same object, instead of separate objects with separate memory. `my_2d_array = [ ["x"] * COLS ] * ROWS`

Answer (score 3):

No, it makes no particular sense to build a larger array then remove some part of it -- just build what you need. Assuming that by "2d array" you actually mean "list of lists":

```
def makarray(value, nrows, ncols):
  return [[value]*ncols for _ in range(nrows)]
```

Comment: Ok, I feel stupid now :)  Also, I think you might have gotten nrows and ncols backwards...

Comment: @Jesse, you're right about the cols/rows (guess you can take the guy out of Fortran but you can't take Fortran out of the guy!-) -- editing now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For so few elements use a dictionary, with tuples as keys:

```
dct = {}
dct[(0,0)] = 'X'
if (10,10) in dct:
    dct[(10,10)] += 1
else:
    dct[(10,10] = 0
# Deleting a row / column
dct.pop((10,0))
dct.pop((10,1))
...
dct.pop((10,10))
```

Dictionaries are very flexible.

Alternatively use a numpy array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to handle it:

```
num_rows, num_cols = 2, 27
table = []

for r in range(num_rows):
    row = []
    table.append(row)
    for c in range(num_cols):
        row.append(c)

print table
```

Comment: This is not bad unless you need to shrink / grow the bad boy. Really all depends on what the asker is trying to do.